# Unsorted directory listing in PHP

Tags: php, list, sorting, directory

This is my code:

```
$ost=$_GET['id']; //get the ID from the URL
$path = "audio/soundtracks/$ost"; //use the ID to select a path

// Open the folder
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

// Loop through the files
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" )
    continue;
    echo "<a href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br />"; //return the name of the track
}

// Close
closedir($dir_handle);
```

It's purpose is to automatically list every sound track cointained in a directory, the name of which is given by the ID passed through the URL. Each track is named with the format "### - title.mp3", e.g. "101 - Overture.mp3".

It works fine, but the resulting list is sorted randomly for some reason. Is there any way to sort the tracks by title? Also, I'm pretty much a newbie with PHP, is there any security issue with the GET function? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The GET is only used to specify the path, it's not supposed to interact with the database. Is this enough to prevent attacks?

```
$ost = $_GET['id']; 
$bad = array("../","=","<", ">", "/","\"","`","~","'","$","%","#");
$ost = str_replace($bad, "", $ost);
$path = "audio/soundtracks/$ost";
```

Comment: Put the data into array first and then sort it. Then output the result of the array. And yes there is a security issue with using get content in path. What happens if I pass in `../../../../` instead of an integer id?

Comment: just use the basename function on GET like this : basename($_GET['id'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some checks on GET parameter before using it. Like checking it is numeric, right lenght etc. And msyql_real_escape_String if used against db.

When looping directory, save files in array in php, with title as index. like this, then you can sort it as you please:

```
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" )
    continue;
    $array[$file] = "<a href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br />"; //return the name of the track
}
```

sort($array);

... after this, loop and print array separately.

It is a better coding practice to first loop to arrays, and then print separatly... in my eyes. It is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking length and using escape string security measures on the $_GET, you can also encode and decode the id into the URL and decode the before using it.

```
//before putting into URL

 $id = $rows["id"];
$id = base64_encode($id);
<a href="yourUrl.php?id='$id'"

//in yourUrl.php

$id = $_GET['id'];
     $id =  base64_decode($id);
```